# Convergence in $L^1$ implies uniform integrability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables and $X$ a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with $X_i\overset{L^1}{\to}X$. Show that $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable, i.e. for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $M>0$ such that $\int_{\{|X_i|>M\}}|X_i|d\mathbb{P}<\epsilon$.

Does someone have a hint?

Comment: don't you also have that all the $X_i$ and $X$ are integrable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Since $X$ is integrable it follows that $\int_E|X|dP \to 0$ as $P(E) \to 0$ so there exits $\delta >0$ such that $\int_{|X_i| >M} |X|dP < \epsilon$ if $P(|X_i| >M) \leq \frac  1 M E|X_i|<\delta$, which is true if $M >\frac  {\sup_iE|X_i|} {\delta}$. Now $\int_{|X_i| >M} |X_i-X|dP \leq E|X_i-X| <\epsilon$ if $i$ is large enough
, say $i \geq i_0$. Combining these two we get uniform integrability. This shows that $\int_{|X_i| >M} |X_i|dP < 2\epsilon$ for all $i \geq i_0$. Now, for eachy $i <i_0$ there exists $M_i$ such that $\int_{|X_i| >M_i} |X_i|dP <\epsilon$. Let $M_0$ be the maximum of $M$ and $M_1,M_2=,...,M_{i_0-1}$. Then $\int_{|X_i| >M_0} |X_i|dP \leq  2\epsilon$ for all $i$.

[I have used the fact that for fixed $i$, $\int_{|X_i| >T} |X_i|dP  \to 0$ as $T\to \infty$. This follows by DCT].

Comment: Do you mean $M>\frac{\sup_i E|X_i|}{\delta}$? But I see, then I can use the triangle inequality.

Comment: @mathemagician99 Yes, you are right. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Actually, I noticed that I made a mistake. I have to show that $\sup_i \int_{|X_i|>M}|X_i|dP<\epsilon$. But for the second inequality the $\epsilon$ depends on the choice of $i$.

Comment: @mathemagician99 See my answer now.